# PHP network devices monitor script

Tags: php, macos, networking, ip

I'm improving an existent Web-based management application for an IPPBX. We would really like that the app detects recently connected IP phones on the network so we can know the MAC address. I've read that a feasible solution would be to fetch that information from DHCP server's leases file, but unfortunately the DHCP server does not tell me which type of device it is referring to in a lease entry. Perhaps I need some network monitoring protocol in order to achieve this.

I'm looking for some hints as a jumpstart so I can write a PHP script that allows me to do that what I explained above. An existent script would be nice too... :)

Comments or feedback welcome and appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I think this is going to be a case of trial and error (in other words Research and Development).

Some things to try:

1. According to [The Mac Address Specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address), the first 3 bytes are organization specific (The OUI).  I would suspect that if your phones are from the same manufacturer, that section should be similar (if not identical).  Something to look at anyway.
2. You figure out a network test to see if it's a phone.  So, first you get the IP address of the device.  Then open a port and try to send an equivalent of a protocol specific ping (in HTTP, it would be a `HEAD` request to port 80), but on a protocol specific to the phones.  All you're looking for is a proper response format (and connection).

Good luck, and have fun.  Projects like these are the best ones in my opinion since they are a challenge and get you thinking and discovering...

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would not suggest doing this in PHP. Write something in a *real* language and then send it to a php script. Anyways, I would go with the lease file. Then use the addresses in the lease file to connect to the new device and determine if its a phone. So you would be connecting to every "new" device on the network. Inefficient but it could work...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an existing application (shameless plug, I wrote it) written in PHP that queries the DHCP leases file and formats it nicely in a webpage:

http://rivetcode.com/software/phpdhcpd/

Code on github:

https://github.com/firefly2442/phpdhcpd